# Failed to install openstack nova-consoleauth ussuri on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: cloud, openstack, nova

I am trying install openstack compute service and after adding ubuntu archive repository with ussuri, installing nova-consoleauth gives this error:

```
nova-consoleauth : Depends: nova-common (= 2:17.0.13-0ubuntu1) but 2:21.1.2-0ubuntu1~cloud0 is to be installed
```

Seems the issue is with nova-common files but I am not sure how to deal with this case.

Someone can help me please!

Answer (score 1):

The `nova-consoleauth` service was removed in Train. See the [release notes](https://docs.openstack.org/releasenotes/nova/train.html). It was used to store the tokens used to secure instance consoles.  This is now done by the Nova database backend.

In other words, don't worry, and just live without it.

Comment: Thank you. So which package is required in order to be able to access the instance console on the web? Currently I am not able to access the console yet I had installed nova-novncproxy. I thought nova-consoleauth is the one providing instance web console

Comment: No package. To troubleshoot console access, check whether Nova's configuration parameters are compatible with your network setup.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found out where the issue was. Opening the console was opening the domain name which was not resolvable. I just updated my /etc/hosts